# find the volume of largest right angled rectangular parallelepiped inscribed in ellipsoid

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

[image]

this problem is from partial differentiation and i need to find the largest volume using differentiation 
question: there is ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$,
find the volume of largest right angled rectangular parallelepiped  inscribed in it. 
$z=c\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$,$V=8cxyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$
and $f(x,y)=cxyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$
$f_x=\frac{y(a^2z^2-c^2x^2)}{a^2z}$$f_y=\frac{x(b^2z^2-c^2y^2)}{b^2z}$
i dont understand why the volume here $V=8cxyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ , can someone explain to me why 8?
and also i cannot picture the rectangular parallelepiped  inside the ellips in three dimensions. 
which one is right $V=xyz $ or $V=8cxyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$
if i use $V=xyz$ i ended up with
$\frac{abc}{3\sqrt3}$

is this picture represent the equation? if someone kind please explain to me using this picture thanks!

Comment: This is an ellipsoid, you should fix the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of a parallelepiped is indeed $V=xyz$. If it is inscribed into an ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$, then $z$ in the volume formula can be replaced by $z$ from the ellipse. Now the picture only shows $1/8$th part (there are $8$ octants) of the whole parallelepiped. Hence: $V_{large}=8V_{small}$. So there are two ways to find the volume of the large parallelepiped: direct or indirect:
$$Direct: \ \ V_{large}=2x\cdot 2y\cdot 2\cdot c\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}.$$
$$Indirect: \ \ V_{large}=8V_{small}=8\cdot x\cdot y\cdot c\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}.$$
Note: It looks one of two $c$s is excessive in the volume formula you provided. However, $f_x, f_y$ were found with one $c$.

Appendix:
$$f_x=yc\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}+xyc\cdot \frac{-\frac{2x}{a^2}}{2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}}=yz-\frac{x^2yc^2}{a^2z}=\frac{y(a^2z^2-c^2x^2)}{a^2z}.$$
Note: After finding $f_x$ the root was replaced by $z$.

Comment: thanks for answering my question! okay so the side will be 2 times @farruhota larger, so it will be 8 times xyz, $f_x, f_y$ , is this $f_x=\frac{y(a^2z^2-c^2x^2)}{a^2z}$ was found by differentiate $ f(x,y)=xyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}} $ ? if it is so, its better to not substitute z to the function, its easier to solve i think(?)

Comment: The problem is to maximize volume of parallelepiped subject to ellipse constraint. There are basically two methods of solution: substitution (presented) and Lagrange multipliers (your suggestion). But remember in LM method the volume function becomes $V=xyz+t(1-x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2-z^2/c^2)$, for which you need to find $V_x, V_y, V_z$. The bottomline is substitution is simpler.

Comment: substitution method here by substitute $z$ to the function? $f_x=\frac{y(a^2z^2-c^2x^2)}{a^2z}$, can you explain how to get $f_x$? i mean we already susbtitute the $z$

Comment: You are right. Using $z$ in $f_x(x,y)$ is not very good idea (what is the sourse?), because next the partials must be equated to zero and $x,y$ must be found, so $z$ must be changed back to $x,y$.

Comment: ok but still i dont understand how to get this $f_x=\frac{y(a^2z^2-c^2x^2)}{a^2z}$ can you explain to me?$ f(x,y)=xyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ we get $f_x$ by differentiate it right? but why there still $z$ ?

Comment: See my appendix above.

Comment: okay i got it!! but why$ f(x,y)=xyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ i mean why there is no 8 in the $f_x$? is this because boundaries(?) and also why did you replace z and not x or y? is it possible to replace the x or y? thanks!!!!!!!!

Comment: Maximizing small parallelepiped is the same as maximizing large. Yes, any variable can be replaced, though it will be cyclic (same expression with different variables).

Comment: if it is the same i can also use the $V=8xyc\sqrt[]{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$ as my $f(x,y)$ and produce same result as the small parallelpiped?

Comment: Yes, because when you equate $f_x$ to zero $8$ will be cancelled and the same critical values will be obtained.

Comment: oh okayy!!! thankyou so much and also which method do you prefer and why? i mean like sometimes for lagrange it is difficult to solve the equations to find the critical point.too

Comment: Well, it depends on the constraint. In general substitution method is considered simpler than LM method.

Comment: okay thankyou!! and alsoi find some of the problems dont provide constrain, and to use LM method,  we need to know the constrain, so i think we have to guess the constrain? like sometimes i have to guess the relation of the provided function with area etc?